# Can "believed" ever be an adjective?

Tags: nouns, adjectives, past-participles, derivational-morphology, inflectional-morphology

The ti­tle ex­plains it all. I had an ar­gu­ment with my English
teacher; she gave us a task to con­vert nouns to their cor­re­spond­ing
ad­jec­tives and verbs.

She gave us *be­lief* as the noun and told us that its cor­re­spond­ing
ad­jec­tive should be *be­liev­able*.  I think that’s true, but I thought
that *be­lieved* should **also** count as a cor­rect an­swer as well.

Am I wrong?

For example, is it wrong to say the fol­low­ing?

> It is a gen­er­ally **be­lieved** fact.

Or should *be­lieved*, for some rea­son, not count as an ad­jec­tive
in that sen­tence?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118934/discussion-on-question-by-darq-can-believed-ever-be-an-adjective).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From the four criteria considered to be the common characteristics of adjectives (CGEL § 7.2 p. 402), can be concluded that "believed" tends towards the status of a full adjective but that its use is subject to much idiomatic constraint.

A) attributive function: Yes but rarely unmodified and if so noun sensitive¹
B) predicative function: Yes but idiomatically restricted
C) modification by *very*: No
D) comparative and superlative form: Yes  but idiomatically restricted

"Believed X"  used if X is one of the following: story, tale, principle, notion.

([generally believed fact](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22generally%20believed%20fact%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en))

**A** ([2014 -  believed proposition](https://books.google.fr/books?id=MlCnAgAAQBAJ&pg=PT139&dq=%22more+believed%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiw8La2_LTuAhVKDGMBHe3NANw4yAEQ6AEwGXoECDwQAg#v=onepage&q=%22more%20believed%22&f=false)) Our paradigm for such basing is the case in which we make a conscious inference from one or more believed propositions to another one.

**D** ([2012](https://books.google.fr/books?id=DJWeBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA106&dq=%22more+believed%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj82dn-77TuAhVWD2MBHRqTAdsQ6AEwXXoECCIQAg#v=onepage&q=%22more%20believed%22&f=false)) In the relative sense, then, the sense in which we contrast reality with simple unreality, and in which one thing is said to have more reality than another, and to be more believed, reality means simply relation to our emotional and active life.

**B** ([2012](https://books.google.fr/books?id=j8-MeLZ4YqIC&pg=PT2464&dq=%22more+believed%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj82dn-77TuAhVWD2MBHRqTAdsQ6AEwOXoECD4QAg#v=onepage&q=%22more%20believed%22&f=false)) . were more familiar and more believed than any of the identified folk beliefs.

**D** ([2010](https://books.google.fr/books?id=54qalyjnU2EC&pg=PR30&dq=%22more+believed%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj82dn-77TuAhVWD2MBHRqTAdsQ6AEwU3oECBEQAg#v=onepage&q=%22more%20believed%22&f=false)) as to render the metal of our true English valour to be the more believed and feared abroad,

**B** **D** ([1760](https://books.google.fr/books?id=PNA1AAAAMAAJ&pg=PA663&dq=%22more+believed%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj82dn-77TuAhVWD2MBHRqTAdsQ6AEwX3oECCAQAg#v=onepage&q=%22more%20believed%22&f=false)) But his dying so “ critically , as it were in the minute in which he seemed " to begin a turn of affairs , made it to be generally the “ more believed , and that the papists had done it , either " by the means of some of lady Portsmouth's servants , or ...

**D** ([2012](https://books.google.fr/books?id=WfXBAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA295&dq=%22more+believed%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiViLis9bTuAhUwyYUKHaQsDCQ4ZBDoATAhegQIVxAC#v=onepage&q=%22more%20believed%22&f=false)) In the relative sense, then, the sense in which we contrast reality with simple unreality, and in which one thing is said to have more reality than another, and to be more believed, reality means simply relation to our emotional and active life.

**B** **D** ([2014](https://books.google.fr/books?id=KMOcAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA219&dq=%22more+believed%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiViLis9bTuAhUwyYUKHaQsDCQ4ZBDoATAmegQIRBAC#v=onepage&q=%22more%20believed%22&f=false)) A speaker who can look a person in the eyes when speaking with them is more believed and trusted.

**B** **D** ([1820](https://books.google.fr/books?id=JhVV_oI0p-QC&pg=PA167&dq=%22more+believed%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiViLis9bTuAhUwyYUKHaQsDCQ4ZBDoATAuegQIPxAC#v=onepage&q=%22more%20believed%22&f=false)) .. and the state or necessity “ of Bishops be more believed.

**B** **D** ([2010](https://books.google.fr/books?id=2Qi6QONXdl4C&pg=PT351&dq=%22more+believed%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiViLis9bTuAhUwyYUKHaQsDCQ4ZBDoATA1egQIRxAC#v=onepage&q=%22more%20believed%22&f=false)) The more specific the praise is, the more believed and appreciated it will be.

**A**  ([2008](https://books.google.fr/books?id=eS-PAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA57&dq=%22more+believed%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjU7tCe-LTuAhUJfBoKHaERAPs4yAEQ6AEwKXoECE0QAg#v=onepage&q=%22more%20believed%22&f=false)) I do believe there are more believed lies told in June than any other month—

This reference shows that "very believed" is considered to be incorrect: [1981 - Lexical Rules of Semantic Interpretation: Control and NP Movement in English and Polish](https://books.google.fr/books?id=hyVKAAAAYAAJ&q=%22very+believed%22&dq=%22very+believed%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwig54jkpbXuAhXbDmMBHT2hD98Q6AEwFHoECDYQAg).

¹<sub>Observation due to [**user Edwin Ashworth**](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/21655/edwin-ashworth)</sub>

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118935/discussion-on-answer-by-lph-can-believed-ever-be-an-adjective).

Answer (score 6):

Dictionaries are often and notoriously incorrect when it comes to part-of-speech designations. However, when the *Oxford English Dictionary* ("[widely regarded as the accepted authority on the English language](https://public.oed.com/about/)") speaks, people listen. Perhaps your teacher will too.

Here's what it has to say (along with a couple of the usage examples given):

> **believed**, *adj.*
>  <sub>**Origin:** Formed within English, by derivation. **Etymons:** BELIEVE *v.*, -ED
> *suffix*<sup>1</sup>.</sub>
>  <sub>**Etymology:** < BELIEVE *v.* + -ED *suffix*<sup>1</sup>.</sub>
>
> Relied on or trusted in as a matter of faith; accepted as true,
> accurate, reliable, or really existent. Also ***believed-in***.
> <sub>1983   P. TAYLOR *Limits of European Integration* vii. 227
>   Attempts to improve standards merged imperceptibly into
> activities to promote the Communities at the believed ‘expense’ of the
> states.</sub>
>  <sub>2007   J. SØRENSEN *Cognitive Theory of
> Magic* ii. 29    Magical actions rest on a believed identity
> between symbol and the symbolised prevalent in traditional
> societies.</sub>
>
> <sub>Source: [*Oxford English Dictionary*](https://oed.com) (login
> required)</sub>

Comment: You misquoted by not finishing the quote: 'It is an unsurpassed guide to the meaning, history, and pronunciation of 600,000 words'. It is not recognised by grammarians as the final authority on POS tagging. John Lawler, above, is a published Professor Emeritus of Linguistics, and is one of many who would say that this is too prescriptive. 'A believed man' is not as acceptable as 'a drowned rat', applying one typical test.

Comment: Also, dictionaries tend not to recognise the functional term of 'modifier'. When they talk of  "believed" being an adjective, they really mean (in grammatical parlance) 'modifier'. A useful rule is if the word cannot be used predicatively, it's probably not an adjective.

Comment: Okay, not bingo then. I must say as an outsider that it is very confusing how some authorities say one thing and others the opposite in English grammar. I don't see this in some other languages I have studied. I am not saying this as a criticism, but just as a constatation. I am at a loss to decide who and what is considered correct and if there is any clear idea of correctness accepted by all.

Comment: In my mother tongue there is no doubt about past participles being used as adjectives. But I see this does not apply to English grammar.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: What do grammarians recognize as "the final authority on POS tagging"? Do you actually believe that 0 linguistics professors, emeritus or otherwise, number among the lexicographers responsible for the (corpus-based) OED?

Comment: @fev Based on my own postgrad professional work in computational linguistics and natural language processing, I cannot see how any “final authority on POS tagging” can ***ever*** exist. POS tag assignment exists only to serve some specific purpose, and such purposes vary widely. Different analyses demand and engender different models. Parts of speech are never some abstract truth, only part of various representational models as unbounded in purpose and number as human imagination. They are purely figmentational constructs, not eternal truths of the universe.

Comment: Does OED correctly classify 'galore' as 'quantifier / adjective', as in all situations it quantifies (many) and adds descriptive comment (sometimes ironic) (gay)?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth No, as it happens the OED does **not** in­clude a ci­ta­tion for *“Visi­tors aplenty and cup­cakes ga­lore for­ever ce­mented the sur­prise party in her child’s mem­ory.”* But I’ll let you de­cide your own pre­ferred POS as­sign­ments for *aplenty* and *ga­lore* there, since I can­not guess whether your POS gamut  is so broad as to in­clude **“post­pos­i­tive at­tribu­tive ad­jec­tives that can­not be used pred­ica­tively nor left of their mod­i­f­i­cand”**.:)

Comment: @tchrist: I am beginning to understand that what you say is the case for the English language. Not the case in my own language. There categories are well defined and unambiguous. However, don't get me wrong, I am sure that both grammatical flexibility and grammatical unambiguousness can be an advantage in a language. I don't know how I have come to be fluent in English using a grammar that I understand now was not very English :) !

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: Per the OED, *galore* "has not yet been revised in OED Third Edition" (its examples from the corpus end at 1863) and "revision of the OED is a long-term project." One imagines that when the OED returns its attention to what CGEL calls a "somewhat dated" word, it might move beyond the word's [etymologically adverbial origins](https://www.etymonline.com/word/galore) to include "adjective," as [others](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/what-kind-of-word-is-galore) have ultimately done—including [other](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/galore) Oxford properties.

Comment: @tchrist: If no final authority on POS tagging can exist, are we in the realm of the **opinion based** then?

Comment: @fev Absolutely not! It’s not opinion.You just first choose (or create) your preferred model, then work within that framework’s definitions. So one model might have nouns and participles but not adjectives (Donatus’s model was like this), while another might have adjectives but not quantifiers or articles or demonstratives as we now have in most modern POS taggers. Is your first language either a Germanic or Romance language that it has allowed you to master English so well as you clearly have? I ask because I may be able to better understand where you're coming from if I knew that.

Comment: @tchrist: My mother tongue is Romanian (Romance language - the closest to Latin, but full of Slavic, Turkish and Greek influences, to simplify it a great deal). I say "opinion based" because it seems to me that if you have chosen one model let's say, and you clash with someone who has chosen a different one, the impression I get is that people do not dialogue about it, but declare that their model is the right one. Well, that sounds pretty "opinion based" to me. Someone was prompted on this site to stop (sic!) using the term "phrasal verb" because it doesn't exist...

Comment: @fev Ah yes, I see. That makes perfect sense now; I work with Romanians with extremely good English. (FWIW, [Sardinian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sardinian_language) also preserves more Latin features than most widely spoken Romance tongues today, but it has so few speakers now nobody thinks of it.)  IIRC, Romanian has only past participles not present ones, and these inflect for number and gender much like an adjective would, whereas its gerunds are invariant just like in Spanish, Portuguese, and Italian. So it’s important to know which you have there. But English has no such concord.

Comment: @tchrist: Yes, you remember right. But neither past participles nor adjectives inflect in English. Anyway, coming to this site has taught me one big lesson. That English grammar is a can of worms (no pejorative connotation intended) that has shattered my image of language in general! I am still looking at this can of worms trying to decide whether I should have a go at it at all... or not. PS: Actually, there are cases of Romanian gerund forms that will inflect according to number and gender. Rather poetical use though.

Comment: @fev There are certain things you can do with some English adjectives or participles that you cannot do with others. These look no different from each other morphologically but they do not function quite the same way as each other syntactically. In some models that makes them sufficiently different that they get awarded different word classes, but in others they don't. Like how you can have a very interesting child but not a very sleeping one, or a child who's asleep but not an asleep child, so now what? :) All POS models suffer from holes like these where no category quite fits some words.

Answer (score 2):

Believed can act as an adjective as any particle can.  The really crucial point is that as such, since [believe](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/believed) means:

> to think that something is true, correct, or real:

it means "to be thought true, correct or real," whereas [believable](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/believable)
means

> belonging to a type that seems real; realistic:

Hence, something can be believed while not being believable (to an objective eye) because the believer is credulous, and vice versa, as when a malicious person believes anything bad that can be said against people, without evidence, and nothing good, regardless of evidence.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118933/discussion-on-answer-by-mary-can-believed-ever-be-an-adjective).